# regular expression in javascript for negative floating point number result stored in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match both positive and negative floating points of any length of characters. I want to Store the result in an Array with double value in it. I tried this

```
input.match(/^[-+]?(\d*)\.?(\d*)$/)
```

For eg. My Number is -123.432 it should return `[-123.432,-123.432]`
If my Number is 23.45 it should return `[23.45,23.45]`

What expression can I use to match negative and positive floating points and get that result back?

Comment: As far as I understand your question correctly, your current regex should do the trick to find the correct numbers. You'll just have to put them manually into the array.
Though, I do suggest to change your regex to "^[-+]?\d+[\.\d]\d*$"

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for replying, but this input.match() returns an array value and in your case its not working as I want, it gives only [23.45] I need array [23.45,23.45]

Answer (score 0):

This should do  :

`[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)`

And test the regex for JS here at : http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Paste your `regexp` and click on `show match` .

Also, look at this link for more info : [FLOATING POINT REGEX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: Hi i have tried that earlier too. but it leaves the negative value. [-23.45,23.45] it has to take [-23.45,-23.45]

Comment: Hi. thanks for the help :) i just have one more doubt, i am taking values after that in "RegExp.$1" can it take negative value ? because i am trying to do it but its not able to take, pls help.

Comment: @Ben10 Did not understand what you meant by that .

Comment: if (input.match(/[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/))
{
this_item.setValue(ezSystem.ezcall("EZUtil.printf", '%1%2',               RegExp.$1.length == 0 ? '0' : RegExp.$1,               RegExp.$2.length == 0 ? '' : '.'.concat(RegExp.$2)));
}
Here In RegExp.$1 Negative value is not coming, while i am trying to 
If I take -23.45, it takes RegExp.$1 as 23.45 IDK why. Pls Help :)

Answer (score 0):

A better regular expression would be:

```
/-?\d+(?:.\d+)?/
```

It matches sequences of at least 1 digits that may start with a `-` sign and may be broken up by a `.`

Your original regular expression also states that this is the entire string (because you add the ^ and $ signs to it). If you want to extract the numbers from a longer text, you shouldn't do that.

Once you have extracted the number (you have the string representation of a floating point), you can use the unary plus operator to convert it to a Number. After that simply create an array with the number twice and you're done.

```
var input = '123.45';
var number = +input;
var arr = [number, number];
```

**NOTE**: as fara as i know, the plus before the floating point doesn't actually belong to the number, so you shouldn't match it. `+123.45` is not a valid floating point. Feel free to change the start to `[+-]?` instead of `-?` if you consider it valid.

Some other examples of floating points i don't consider valid:

```
+123
.123
-.123
123.
```

**EDIT:** Working JsBin: http://jsbin.com/ehurAva/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your question

Is it that you want to have the same value as a result on `array[0]` and `array[1]`? It's pointless to do so; also you can just write some code to do it for you, instead of forcing regexp to do so.

But it's possible - you can just hide groups by putting `?:` at the beginning of it or just skip them if they are not needed. You can create additional groups by just adding more parentheses. So your regexp modified will look like this:

```
input.match(/^([-+]?\d*\.?\d*)$/)
```

It makes no sense though

Comment: Hi Adassko, thanks for the help :) i just have one more doubt, i am taking values after that in "RegExp.$1" can it take negative value ? because i am trying to do it but its not able to take, pls help.

Comment: can you show me some code sample of what you're trying to do?

Comment: if (input.match(/[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/)) { this_item.setValue(ezSystem.ezcall("EZUtil.printf", '%1%2', RegExp.$1.length == 0 ? '0' : RegExp.$1,  RegExp.$2.length == 0 ? '' : '.'.concat(RegExp.$2))); } Here In RegExp.$1 Negative value is not coming, while i am trying to If I take -23.45, it takes RegExp.$1 as 23.45 IDK why. Pls Help :)

Comment: that's because the sign is not within parentheses. Every `$N` variable corresponds to specific matching group indicated by parentheses counted from the left. You can just use `$_` instead of `$1` to get the whole matching with sign included